# ui file Layout setting not working in PyQt

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyqt, qwidget, qlayout

I have a very minimalistic `QWidget` setup, consisting of two classes. `MainWindow` and `MainWidget`.
Both are loaded as .ui files, which results in a working GUI in Qt (run with QtCreator), but when I try to run it with PyQt the layout of the `MainWidget` does not take effect.

main.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = MyMainWindow()
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

mainwidget.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic

class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("mainwidget.ui", self)
```

in `mainwidget.ui` a HorizontalLayout is set for the widget. Looks fine in both QtCreator's Designer and when run with it. Only when I run the python code the Layout does not take effect. When I maximize the window, the content of the `MainWidget` stays small.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't see where you instantiate mainwidget.

Comment: It's part of the ui file. I added a `QWidget` and specified the custom class as `MainWidget`

Comment: I checked `self.layout()` in the `MainWidget` right now, and it says `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout`, so it _does_ have the layout, it doesn't take effect though.

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit

```
class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
```

in your main.py

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Is this new behavior? Am I missing functionality by not inheriting `QMainWindow`?

Comment: Well, I had a similar case yesterday and solved it that way.
With
`self.ui = uic.loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)`
you work on a widget, so I thought I should inherit QWidget. That's how I fixed my problem

Comment: MyMainWindow is definitely the main entry point of the application, and it should show a window frame etc., so QMainWindow seems more fitting to me. And doesn't QMainWindow inherit from QWidget?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution, but a workaround.

The problem here seems to be, that the `MainWidget` is not initialized properly (as [mFoxRu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1555950/mfoxru) made me question).

The way I had it set up, I defined `MainWidget` as a custom class for my central widget. That way the Layout was broken.

The workaround is to not set a custom class for the central widget, and set a instance of `MainWidget` to the central widget at runtime.

Resulting changes in python:

```
self.setCentralWidget(mainwidget.MainWidget())
```

directly after `loadUi` in `main.py`